# Horizontal Scroll on Site only on Safari / Large body Background Image

Tags: html, css, safari

A site I'm working on has a background image on the body elements that is 3000px wide. The site itself is site to 100% width and this works fine in Chrome and Firefox. You just see whatever will fit in the screen and the overflow is hidden.

When I use Safari, the site has a horizontal scroll that extends until you reach the end of the 3000px background image. If I use the inspector on Google or Safari, when you hover over 'body' or 'html', the bounding box isn't 3000px, it's the 100% width of the site. If I try to set overflow:hidden on either body or html, it doesn't fix it. I've tried to explicitly set body and HTML and to width and max-width of 100% and that doesnt work. I've tried to set no-scroll properties and that doesn't work.

Any ideas on why this would be happening only on Safari?

Comment: The greater parent element needs to have it's width in **px**. Then the children elements can have 100% of it. Then you need to give the background style fixed. I cannot add other than that, without seeing some code and css.

Comment: And a screen shot will also help.